# How to handle webview popup close in android?

Tags: android, html, android-webview, popupwindow

I am trying to implement paytab payment in android, which uses popup window for further varification, but I cannot handle popup in android webview.

For testing I have created two simple html files for showing and closing popups

window.html

```
<html>
<head>

   <script language="Javascript">

       function showFBWindow(){
           url = "allowfbchild.html"
           newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
           if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
       }

   </script>

</head>
<body>

   <input type="button" OnClick="showFBWindow()" value="Open FB" />

</body>
</html>
```

allowfbchild.html

```
<html>
<head>

   <script language="Javascript">

       function redirectToFB(){
          // window.opener.location.href="http://192.168.1.7/window.html";
           self.close();
       }

   </script>
<h1>hello</h1>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>hello</h1>
   <input type="button" value="Ok" OnClick="redirectToFB()" />
<a href="www.google.com">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried this in my android activity: (Suggest if any other workaround to do this)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    RelativeLayout main;

    //  @Override
    //  public void onBackPressed()
    //  {
    //      if (webView.canGoBack())
    //          webView.goBack();
    //      else
    //          super.onBackPressed();
    //  }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        try
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

            WebView webView = new WebView(this);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeclient());

            main.addView(webView);

            webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.7/window.html");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {

            System.err.println("load url" + url);
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            System.err.println("finish url" + url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            System.err.println("error:" + description);
        }
    }

    private class MyWebChromeclient extends WebChromeClient
    {

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg)
        {
            System.err.println("create new");
            WebView newWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
            newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            main.addView(newWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window)
        {
            super.onCloseWindow(window);
            System.err.println("closing");
//          main.removeViewAt(main.getChildCount() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest solution for this. Thanx.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am stuck here